# Datetime field overflow when uploading csv file to SQL Server Database using BCP

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, datetime, bcp

I have been trying for days to fix this problem. I have a Pandas dataframe which I export to a csv file like this:

```
df.to_csv(csv_name, index=False, header = False, encoding='utf-8-sig', sep='\t')
```

I need to upload this csv file to a SQL Server Database using BCP, using this command:

```
bcp [DB].[dbo].[Table] in file.csv -Sserver -Uuser -Ppass -c -C65001  -t "\t" -e error.log
```

Every time I run it, I get this error:

```
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.
```

When looking at the error.log, I see there is a problem with my date value I want to upload. In the table definition, the date format is "smalldatetime". The actual value I want to upload is "2020-05-30 12:55:22".

I am just exporting a one row dataframe to csv.

This is the error message I receive (which also shows the content of the csv file):

```
@ Row 1, Column 8: Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding. @#
165405677   156147965   1135358 1425879 3.5 "Nice value Bordeaux Blend 
Deep purple color.  Blackberry   plum    tobacco and oaky with hints of pepper.  Full-bodied     dry and slightly spicy taste.
Let it breathe for at least 1 hr
Pairs well with pecorino and salami crostini
#uncorkingArgentina"    en  2020-05-30T19:55:42.000Z    True    2   444897692   67  8   "49  292     320     334     422"   "'blackberry'    'oaky'  'pepper'    'plum'  'tobacco'" 3353    0   Completed   89036   3.7 536982,90,Normal,71,3.6,484,26,,,"Nice value Bordeaux Blend 
Deep purple color.  Blackberry, plum, tobacco and oaky with hints of pepper.  Full-bodied, dry and slightly spicy taste.
Let it breathe for at least 1 hr
Pairs well with pecorino and salami crostini
#uncorkingArgentina",False,True
```

This is my table definition in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [Table] (

    [column1] bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    [column2] bigint,
    [column3] bigint,
    [column4] bigint,
    [column5] float(53),
    [column6] nvarchar(1500) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8, 
    [column7] nvarchar(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column8] smalldatetime, 
    [column9] bit,
    [column10] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column11] bigint,
    [column12] integer,
    [column13] integer,
    [column14] nvarchar(150) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column15] nvarchar(500) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column16] bigint,
    [column17] integer,
    [column18] nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column19] integer,
    [column20] float(53),
    [column21] integer,
    [column22] integer,
    [column23] nvarchar(60) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column24] integer,
    [column25] float(53),
    [column26] integer,
    [column27] integer,
    [column28] nvarchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column29] nvarchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column30] nvarchar(1500) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    [column31] bit,
    [column32] bit
)
GO
```

I tried to upload another rows, but I always have a problem with the date value of each one of them, no matter what the other content of the row is.

I tried everything to fix it. What do you think is the reason of this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you change the SQL table column to a `datetime` datatype? If you can't then BCP into a staging table then cast the date field into your `live` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data into a staging table where all the columns are strings.

Then you can look at the data and determine where the conversion error is happening, using logic such as:

```
select s.*
from staging s
where try_convert(smalldatetime, column8) is null and column8 is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the Python package `bcpandas` to automate the BCP part of sending a Pandas dataframe to SQL Server.  I had values with too much precision for SQL Server, like `2024-02-29 12:02:56.834863` and was getting this error.

I used this command to lower the precision of my datetime column:

```
logs['action_date'] = pd.to_datetime(logs['action_date']).dt.floor('ms')
```

After which the write with BCP succeeded.